# Unauthenticated bucket listing possible with boto?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I am using boto to interact with S3 buckets, and in some cases I just want to be able to list a publicly-readable bucket without passing my credentials. If I pass credentials, boto actually does not let me list the bucket even though it is publicly visible. Is it possible to connect to S3 and list a bucket *without* passing credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs don't mention it, but after digging into the code I discovered a hidden kwarg that solves my problem:

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(anon=True)
```

Then you can call `conn.get_bucket()` on any bucket that is publicly readable.

Comment: One extra thing worth noting: if you use anon access, most things work, but one thing that doesn't is `generate_url`. See https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1540

Answer (score 0):

I find that this works without creds if you are just reading the head of the bucket:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(options.bucket)
s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket.name)
```

I [use it](https://github.com/alexbuz/S3_Sanity_Check) when I need to ping my bucket for readability.